# Initialize router events from a template file in a Vaadin (20) Flow project

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-router

I have a Vaadin 20 application that is Flow-based. All views are written in Java, and the routes are set up with Java. I wanted to have a nicer navigation component, so I created a [frontend TS template for my project](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/templates/basic), as `frontend/src/vaadin-nav.ts`. It has a bunch of `<a>` elements for navigation purposes.

My question is, how should I link to the server-side routes correctly from the template? I have e.g. `AboutView.java` with `@Route(value = "about", layout = MainView.class)`. How can I tell in the template that "navigate to 'about'"? I tried checking [the Router instructions for Fusion](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/fusion/routing/router/#using-the-router), but they require that I have set up a client-side router object with an outlet. I don't want to do that because I already have a `MainView.java` that sets up the routing and outlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vaadin 20 always uses the client-side Vaadin Router. In an application with Flow views and a server-side `MainView.java` or similar, the client-side router is simply delegating all routing decisions to the server and using the root of the page as the router outlet.

The client-side router is intercepting clicks on local `<a href>` links (e.g. not linking to a separate hostname) and treats those as router actions. If there isn't a client-side route, then it delegates to the server.

What this means is that `<a href="about">About</a>` should be enough in your `vaadin-nav.ts` file.

Comment: That worked! I had a bunch of nonexisting routes configured but it always showed the default view when I clicked on them, so I thought they didn't work. I was expecting a "route not found" page for a nonexisting route. But now when I configured one with "about", it navigated there! Thanks.

Comment: Default view for nonexistent instead of an error page sounds like a bug in Vaadin, unless you have the default view as `@Route("/*")` or similar so that it would catch anything that isn't explicitly defined?